# How to change screen brightness on Toshiba Satellite L850-DJS in Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, brightness

I bought a laptop Toshiba Satellite L850-DJS. There was Windows 8 installed at. I installed Kubuntu 12.10. All works perfectly, but i can't change screen brightness.
Maybe someone had this problem and helps me.

Comment: directory 
/sys/class/backlight
is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it the easy way:

http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/how-to-make-brightness-changes-permanent-in-your-linux-desktop/

Comment: Thank you for response. But it doesn't work, because my directory
/sys/class/backlight
is empty

The main problem is that no devices for changing brightness was found in my system.

Comment: That means you are missing acpi-support on your machine. It is usually installed by default in most distributions, but since it is not there in your case, you can try this: sudo apt-get install acpi-support

Comment: There is the last version of acpi-support is installed in my system...

Comment: In that case are you having the 3.4 kernel? It did break some backlight things. You can verify it by typing "uname --a" in a terminal. If yes, then you may either upgrade your kernel, or add acpi_backlight=vendor in menu.lst as given in this link: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142578

Comment: My kernel has version: 3.5.0-25-generic

Comment: My kernel has version: 3.5.0-25-generic
Also option acpi_backlight=vendor is already added. And option acpi_osi=Linux is added too.
Also proprietary drivers (AMD) are installed.
I tried to compile kernel 3.7 and i had same problem anyway.
Also i tried to boot with live-version of Fedora 18 and the last version of OpenSuse, and problem was be...

Comment: If you are facing the same problem with Fedora 18 and other distributions, then it seems to be some hardware issue pertaining to your machine/setup only. Raise this bug with Kubuntu and see what happens.

Comment: There is no same problem in preinstalled windows8, hardware is fine. I don't know to do...

Comment: Windows-8 is a totally different OS and handles things differently at the system level. What I meant by hardware-issue is that I think there is something about your hardware that the Linux kernel is not able to handle - Not that there are any problems with your hardware itself. Hence, I suggested you to raise this at Kubuntu (or even KDE) so that they can take it further.

Comment: I'm going to install windows8 to external hdd, and then take its DSDT table (and decompile) to understand how windows works with acpi. Also I'll try to recompile Linux kernel with this DSDT (or edited and recompiled DSDT). I think this idea is not too bad. I hope i'll have some information, that will help me...
Thank for you responses =)

Comment: I updated to Kubuntu 13.04 (kernel 3.8). And now backlight changing works! I thing problem was in kernel (no expected hardware support was be). Thanks for you response. Problem solved! =)

Comment: I installed proprietary AMD drivers and backlight doesn't work again...

Comment: After deleting driver backlight works again. Why driver and backlight changing don't work together?...